# I want to stop a .bat file, then start it again

Tags: batch-file

I have a menu for my discord bot, and my discord bot has a starter bat file, it just starts the python file. But in the menu, I want to create a restart button for the bot, but I can't. I only want to stop the file, then start it again. I tried to use os.close, but I've got an error: "an integer is required (got type str)"

```py
def stop():
    os.close('C:\\Codeok\\Discord_bot\\bot_start.bat')
```

That's how the code for the off button.

Comment: How do you start the `.bat` file? Do you want to have a GUI? Have you looked at any GUI tutorials?

Comment: Welcome! You should update your question with what you've tried already and where you're having trouble. Take a look at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dont just spawn the python process. use this:

```
wmic process call create "D:\Python39\python.exe c:\xx.py"
Executing (Win32_Process)->Create()
Method execution successful.
Out Parameters:
instance of __PARAMETERS
{
        ProcessId = 1234;
        ReturnValue = 0;
};
```

This would give the pid. Save it somewhere and then when the time comes to restart, kill the pid process using:

```
TASKKILL /PID 1234
```